# Lampp and wkhtmltopdf not working from shell_exec

Tags: php, ubuntu, wkhtmltopdf, lampp

Im trying to run the following php script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$cmd = "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf http://www.yahoo.com /opt/lampp/htdocs/filer/yahoo.pdf";
$t = shell_exec($cmd);
exit();
```

I have `wkhtmltopdf` installed and it works perfectly from the command line. However when i run the php script above i get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
```

I've tried to copy my `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_s.so` to `/opt/lampp/lib/`
Without success.

Any ideas?